# Find all root of an equation between a given range

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sympy

I am trying to find all the root between a range of an equation as:

```
def f(x):
  return np.tan(x) - 3*x

from scipy.optimize import fsolve

In [14]: fsolve(f,0)
Out[14]: array([ 0.]) # one of the root of the eqn
```

But for any other initial guess, it gives 0 unless the initial guess is very close to the root.

```
In [15]: fsolve(f, 2)
Out[15]: array([ 0.])  # expected ouptut 1.32419445
In [16]: fsolve(f,[1.32])
Out[16]: array([ 1.32419445])

In [17]: fsolve(f, 5)
Out[17]: array([ 0.])  # expected ouptut 4.64068363
In [18]: fsolve(f,[4.64])
Out[18]: array([ 4.64068363])
```

Is there any way to find all the root between a given range?

Comment: You could try [Brent's method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html).

Answer (score 1):

Every function, like a piece of wood, has its own "grain" that can present problems when working with it. One of my favorite methods is to rearrange the expression to get rid of the variable in the denominator. In your case, solving as `sin(x)-3*x*cos(x)` has a much better behavior:

```
>>> [nsolve(sin(x)-3*x*cos(x),i).n(2) for i in range(10)]
[0, 1.3, 1.3, -1.3, 4.6, 4.6, 1.3, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8]
```

Continuation is also a useful method for ill behaved functions. In this case, using a parameter to slowly turn on the ill-behaved part of the function can be useful. In your case, the `x` in `3*x*cos(x)` makes things more difficult. But if you divide by the approximate value you are seeking and slowly change that divisor to 1 you can follow the approximate root to the desired root. Here is an example:

```
>>> a = 0.
>>> for j in range(5):
...  for i in range(10):
...   a = nsolve(sin(x)-3*x*cos(x)/(a + i*(1-a)/9),a)
...  print(a)
...  a += pi.n()+0.1
...
0
4.64068363077555
7.81133447513087
10.9651844009289
14.1135533715145
```

Answer (score 0):

If a simple binary search suits you, and you can provide x's for which f has different signs, the following might help:

```
from math import *

eps = 1e-20

def test_func(x):
    return tan(x) - 3*x

def find_root(f, a, b):
    for i in range(20):
        x = i / 10.0
        print(x, f(x))
    fa = f(a)
    fb = f(b)
    if fa*fb > 0:
        raise ("f(a) and f(b) need to have different signs")
    while True:
        if fabs(fa) < eps:
            return a
        elif fabs(fb) < eps:
            return b
        else:
            m = (a + b) / 2
            fm = f(m)
            if m == a or m == b:
                return m
            if fa*fm > 0:
                a, fa = m, fm
            else:
                b, fb = m, fm

r = find_root(test_func, 1.0, 1.5)
print (r, test_func(r))  # 1.324194449575503 3.1086244689504383e-15
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to check all the roots between a given range. As it works only when f(a)*f(b) < 0  so hard to choose a & b.